# NO VELOCITY SERVERS Up Error

Tags: vora

I am getting Error while creating table in zeppelin as , "Could not load table TEST_TABLE_1 : There are no Velocity servers up."

All services in AMBARI are in green status. Tried restarting servers , instances and all services but still error exists.

Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if the Vora servers are running on your Spark worker nodes:

```
ps -efa | grep v2server
```

Could you provide the command you are executing and a bit more details about the error message (e.g. 1-2 lines before; 1-2 lines after).

Where are you running your cluster (AWS, datacenter, laptop,...)?